# Unresolved reference: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with spring-boot-starter-security Gradle/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, spring-security, build.gradle

I am new to using Gradle and Kotlin, and I am trying to set up a simple API key authentication for my Spring Boot application. I added spring-boot-starter-security to my build.gradle.kts file, but in my SecurityConfig file, the import for

`org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` 
is unresolved. The other security imports are fine. For example,

`org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity` 
works just fine. I am using Intellij, and I thought maybe it was a caching issue, but it has persisted after invalidating cache, as well.

Here is my build.gradle.kts file.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.0.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
}

group = "com.demo"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am referencing this medium article: https://medium.com/techwasti/enable-spring-security-using-kotlin-6b9abb36d218

My SecurityConfig file is under src/main/kotlin/com.demo.dashboard/config.

I tried restarting the IDE, referencing the spring security dependency in different ways in the build.gradle.kts file, and re-initializing the project with the dependency selected from the start, but I have had no luck.

Comment: and the article you are referencing is 3 years old.

Comment: Guess I forgot it’s not 2020 anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` [has been deprecated last year](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), in Spring Security 5.7.

From quick search in the java doc, [the class no longer exists in 6.0.3 (latest version)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/package-summary.html). From the build.gradle file you posted, you are using the latest version.

The article under first link describes alternative approaches to configuring spring security.
[This article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter) may also be helpful.